# when I executed "jQuery.prepend(HTML)", HTML is exposed only after clicking refresh button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, require

After sending AJAX request to POST, it receives JSON data.

At success, I call the function defined in `require.js`.

```
Function name: function (arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) {

    require(['Common'], function (Common) {
    var template = <div Blabla> ~~~~~~;

    $('Class name').prepend($(template));

  });
}
```

In the above function declaration, 'HTML' is directly output asynchronously,

If I wrapped it with 'if' to specify a specific number, I would not get it right.

```
Function name: function (arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) {

    require(['Common'], function (Common) {
    
    if ($('class name to prepend').length <5) {
      var template = <div Blabla> ~~~~~~;

      $('Class name').prepend($(template));

      }
  });
}
```

If I write 'if' there, it prints 'HTML' added after page refresh

Comment: How about posting actual code and not a bunch of syntax errors... [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: simply use $('#selector').val().length

Comment: Oops, I could not identify the duplicate class name.
Thank you for your favor.